# Chrome Extension Login Security

Tags: security, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I have a website where users can signup and I want to provide some features using a chrome extension, I'm a bit concerned about security:

My idea is to show a login form in a popup and then send an ajax request to my server with username/password (using HTTPS) and then store a token into localStorage that is used for following ajax calls.

Is this insecure? Why? I don't understand how this is more insecure then using a form on my website for example or logging sending an ajax request from a client side js framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is secure, as long as you handle the token properly on the client side (i.e. only submit it to your site, and no other sites).  The danger is that you are essentially going around the work that Google and the open source community has done to secure Chrome/Chromium from XSS, CSRF, and other token stealing attacks.  Make sure that no other sites can request the token from your extension (this is done in the browser through same-domain enforcement).  You will need to use certificate signing to verify the origination of the request (you should be able to reuse the private certificate that you use for SSL).

It is important that you treat all client requests as malicious even if they originate from your extension.  The server must perform all secure processing as if the client were completely compromised.  On the server side, you shouldn't even know if the user is using your extension or a regular browser, because security wise it doesn't matter.

As for the storing of the login credentials on the client side, you should never store the password in plain text.  You should salt and hash it, and submit that hash to the server.  Based on your question, it sounds like you wouldn't store the user's credentials anyway, just a token.  If that is the case, and the token doesn't contain anything sensitive, you should have no problem storing it.  Make sure though that you expire tokens on the server side and force re-authentication periodically.

*Answer was edited for clarification and typos*

Comment: If I were to salt and hash something, where would the secrete be stored on chrome extension (client) side?

Comment: You lost me at saving the hash of the password locally and sending the hash to the server to login. Although that would prevent someone from using the local credentials to login to other websites that share the password, it won't stop them from using local credentials to login to your service. At least store the auth token returned by the login method. That way, people won't be able to call login without knowing the actual password and you can expire tokens on server side to throw out any freeloaders

Comment: @nurettin I don't see where we have a disagreement.  I wasn't saying you should store the username/password rather than a token, simply that if you _do_ it should be in a salted/hashed format (the original question seemed ambiguous about whether or not they were asking about storing the username/pass or just a token, also other people may find themselves here with a slightly different scenario).  Storing the token is definitely the better way to do it.  I also specifically mentioned that you should expire token on the server side.

Comment: The difference is: "I would not do that at all" (me) vs "I would do it like this if I did" (you) when storing information about the password.

Comment: Ah, I guess to be clear I would not do it at all either.  But since I'm not a dictator and can't prevent others, at least don't store my password in plain text :-)